# Is there a way to limit the range of x, when using dates in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to set a range for the dates that I display on the x axis.

I would like to have 0 as the first value of my series, and then set the ticker so it will show only 3 days.

I have set the axis to display ticks in days, but I am not able to neither limit this to a specific amount of days (say 3 days), nor I can figure out how to start the series at a specific time (say 8 AM) and end it at the same time (so I have x divided in 3 equal range of time, all starting and ending at the same time).

This is what I have so far:

```
jsfiddle.net/newbiez/N3xsr/3/
```

Comment: What do you mean "have 0 as the first value"? Is the only problem you are having in setting the exact start and end time of the values shown on the x-axis?

Comment: Let me rephrase: 0 as the origin of the x axis, should have a set date; so if the first date of my series is "Jul 13 2014 10:30", I would like to have at origin "Jul 13 2014 9:00"; instead of the blank value that I see now. Also I would like to limit the range, so the end is always at the same time of the start, but limited to a specific number of days (so I would display "Jul 16 2014 9:00" as end date, if the starting one is on the 13th

Comment: Okay. So specific start and end time. But from what I understand, you also want the ticks to display at that time? You want a tick to be exactly at the origin of the x axis?

Comment: So I can just get the first value of the series; and change it to 9:00, to set the start point in the series settings? My data change often during the day. I would like for the tick to start at 0, so the date is not actually on the tick, but is in between; which is more correct since it is displaying a range, and not a point. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to define the exact start and end time of the `datetime` x-axis is the `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max` with `Date.UTC` or just regular timestamps like this:

```
xAxis: {
    min: Date.UTC(2001, 5, 13, 9), // Or timestamp 992422800000
    max: Date.UTC(2001, 5, 16, 9) // Or timestamp 992592000000
}
```

Also, in order to have the ticks start exactly at this minimum value, and from there happen at regular intervals, you could use the `xAxis.tickPositioner` function, as shown here:

```
xAxis: {
    tickPositioner: function () {
        var positions = [],
            // The first tick position (min value of axis)
            tick = this.min,
            // Distance between ticks, from first tick
            increment = 24 * 3600 * 1000;

        // Create list of tick positions (up to max value of axis)
        for (; tick - increment <= this.max; tick += increment) {
            positions.push(tick);
        }

        return positions;
    }
}
```

As demonstrated in this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/N3xsr/4/).

Comment: Thanks OndKloss; I presume that I can use also regular date instead than UTC; otherwise I will have to convert back and forth every time that the chart has to be drawn. Thanks again!

Comment: As long as you have end up with a timestamp it'll be fine!

Comment: You need to use timestamps, not any custom values.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Sebastian; I just saw your comment. I was wondering why when I was passing a string in UTC format, it didn't like it. So I need to translate in timestamp and then pass it to the max and min.

Comment: Something like this `min: new Date('2001 Jun 12 09:00 +00:00').getTime()`?

Comment: Found another way: I just put the first value of the serie in a temp var, then I use the setHour and setMinutes to change it, and then I pass it to min. Strange thing is that when I set for example 15:00 (which is 3 PM), the series start at 21:17 (9:17 PM), which makes no sense to me

Comment: @newbiez That is probably the GMT offset